# How to get json with Vue and Fetch Api

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple code based on Vue.js:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: 'vue-app',
    data: {
        displayedBooks: {}
    },
    created() {
        fetch('/library').then(response => response.json())
            .then((data) => this.data.displayedBooks = data);
    }
});
```

But I got an exception:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'displayedBooks' of undefined at fetch.then.then (main.js:8)

Why this simple code is not works well?

Comment: It'd just be `this.displayedBooks`, not `this.data.displayedBooks`. Everything in your Vue `data` parameter gets attached to `this` directly.

Comment: This is a plain typo: it should be `this.displayedBooks = data` :)

Comment: Another gotcha can be that "this" in this.data.displayedBooks can be the Ajax library and not the Vue instance. If this is the problem then define: var vm = this; then use vm.data.displayedBooks for where to pass the data back to.

Comment: Here, in comments a got a all answers! Use `this.displayedBooks` and don't forget about store context with `var self = this` in `created()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: 'vue-app',
    data: {
        displayedBooks: {}
    },
    created() {
        fetch('/library').then(response => {
            this.displayedBooks = response.data
    }, error =>{
       console.log(error)
   })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It'd just be `this.displayedBooks`, not `this.data.displayedBooks`. Everything in your Vue data parameter gets attached to this directly.